# C++: best practice architecture for multiple implementations of a class function?

Tags: c++

What is the best way in C++ to implemented multiple versions of the same class member function, without cluttering your class interface?

In search of the most efficient method to compute something, I often measure resource requirements (time, space, etc) of multiple implementations of the same function. I should add that the intent is to *keep those implementations* even after comparison one has proven to be better than another. In C++ I came up with something that provides the following interface:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.Print();

    foo.Add();                   // adds 1
    foo.Print();

    foo.Implementation1::Add();  // adds 10
    foo.Print();

    foo.Implementation2::Add();  // adds 100
    foo.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

The full code can be found in a [Git repository](https://github.com/gisodal/multidef). Although I like that this interface provides clear distinction between each implementation and you can call it on the same object, the method used to accomplish this is not pretty: I access values in the base class from the derived class. This approach requires that we make the class for which we want to make multiple implementations a derived class, which has a base class for every individual implementation. Also, I have to friend the base classes. I am getting goosebumps... no... nightmares.. :)

Without cluttering a class by adding `Add1()`, `Add2()`, etc., to your class, what is a good architecture for have multiple implementations of class member functions?

Comment: You could keep it simple: make a single `enum` parameter with default value and do `switch`.

Comment: With such a simple example (which is ok, we _do_ want a [repro]), I would question everything. Why are you writing classes at all, and so on. But since you're explicitly asking _What is the best way in C++ to implemented multiple versions of the same **class member function**_, what about telling us what of the current design _can't_ be changed and what can? Besides, I believe having all the needed code in the question would make it more readable. I can't really bother opening several tabs at the same time to see all the parts of your example.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this exactly what you're looking for but you could do something like this.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    int x = 0;

    public:
    template <std::size_t N = 1>
    void add();

    void print() {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
void Foo::add<1>() {
    x += 1;
}

template <>
void Foo::add<2>() {
    x += 10;
}

template <>
void Foo::add<3>() {
    x += 100;
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.print();

    f.add();
    f.print();

    f.add<2>();
    f.print();

    f.add<3>();
    f.print();
    return 0;
}
```

You can keep the specializations in the .cpp to avoid having to expose all the implementations in your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I want to be able to define different implementations for a function, whether they are inside a library or outside. The answer of [super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super) helped me with finding the solution below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class foo
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  void print();
};

struct LOWERCASE;
struct UPPERCASE;

template <>
void foo::print<LOWERCASE>()
{
  std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
}

template <>
void foo::print<UPPERCASE>()
{
  std::cout << "HELLO WORLD!" << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
  foo f;
  f.print<LOWERCASE>();
  f.print<UPPERCASE>();
  // f.print<int>();
  return 0;
}
```

This will give the following output:

```
hello world!
HELLO WORLD!
```

And when `// f.print<int>();` is uncommented the compiler will complain as follows:

> undefined reference to `void foo::print()'

I hope this is helpful for other people that may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant-based_programming) paradigm which is actually not existing in C++ itself yet.

What i can suggest is to use compiler specific function [multi-versioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Multiversioning.html):

```
__attribute__ ((target ("default")))
int foo ()
{
  // The default version of foo.
  return 0;
}

__attribute__ ((target ("sse4.2")))
int foo ()
{
  // foo version for SSE4.2
  return 1;
}
```